# How to set a semi-transparent background image in Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, graphics

Here is the sample code to draw a semi-transport `Widget` using `QT library`in `c++`.

```
QMainWindow window;
window.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
window.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
window.setFixedSize(800, 600);

QWidget widget(&window);
widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 128)");

window.setCentralWidget(&widget);
window.show();
```

Is it possible to set a semi-transparent image (`PNG` or so) instead of just simple color as a `Widget` background like above? If so Can someone please provide a sample code?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a QLabel to display the image and then overlay other widgets on top of it. Here's a sample code to set a semi-transparent image as a widget background:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow window;
    window.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
    window.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
    window.setFixedSize(800, 600);

    // Load your semi-transparent image
    QPixmap backgroundImage("path/to/your/image.png");

    QLabel backgroundLabel(&window);
    backgroundLabel.setPixmap(backgroundImage);
    backgroundLabel.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600);  // Set the label size to match the window
    backgroundLabel.setScaledContents(true);     // Scale the image to fit the label

    QWidget contentWidget(&window);
    contentWidget.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600);
    contentWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 128)");

    // Make the content widget semi-transparent
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello, World!", &contentWidget);
    label->setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 30);

    window.setCentralWidget(&contentWidget);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

You can make mainwindow and any other widget movable (dragable) if you use subclassing. The below example contains both a movable window and label.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class DraggableMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    DraggableMainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent), isDragging(false) {}

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            isDragging = true;
            dragStartPosition = event->globalPos() - this->frameGeometry().topLeft();
        }
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
        if (isDragging) {
            this->move(event->globalPos() - dragStartPosition);
        }
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            isDragging = false;
        }
    }

private:
    bool isDragging;
    QPoint dragStartPosition;
};

class MovableLabel : public QLabel
{
public:
    MovableLabel(const QString& text, QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QLabel(text, parent), isDragging(false) {}

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            isDragging = true;
            dragStartPosition = event->globalPos() - pos();
        }
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
        if (isDragging) {
            move(event->globalPos() - dragStartPosition);
        }
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            isDragging = false;
        }
    }

private:
    bool isDragging;
    QPoint dragStartPosition;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    DraggableMainWindow window;
    window.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
    window.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
    window.setFixedSize(800, 600);

    QPixmap backgroundImage("path/to/your/image.png");

    QLabel backgroundLabel(&window);
    backgroundLabel.setPixmap(backgroundImage);
    backgroundLabel.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600);
    backgroundLabel.setScaledContents(true);

    QWidget contentWidget(&window);
    contentWidget.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600);
    contentWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 128)");

    MovableLabel label("Hello World!", &contentWidget);
    label.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 30);

    window.setCentralWidget(&contentWidget);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```